# How to increment line counter for line beginning replacements by AWK/...?

Tags: text-processing, awk, nl

I first thought about SED (`sed "s/^/COUNTER \&/" /tmp/1.tex`) but it is designed for a single line, and I cannot increment the counter itself by sed so thinking now `awk` because I have great experiences with `gawk` in integrated approaches. 
Data

```
What & South Dragon & North Dragon    & 5 \\ \hline
What & South Dragon & North Dragon    & 5 \\ \hline
What & South Dragon & North Dragon    & 5 \\ \hline
```

Expected output

```
1 & What & South Dragon & North Dragon    & 5 \\ \hline
2 & What & South Dragon & North Dragon    & 5 \\ \hline
3 & What & South Dragon & North Dragon    & 5 \\ \hline
```

OS: Debian 8.5

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`nl` is a utility to number the lines of a file.Usage:

```
nl /path/to/file
```

In your specific case:

```
$ nl  -s ' & ' input.txt                                                                                                 
     1 & What & South Dragon & North Dragon    & 5 \\ \hline
     2 & What & South Dragon & North Dragon    & 5 \\ \hline
     3 & What & South Dragon & North Dragon    & 5 \\ \hline
```

Comment: How can you combine this with preappending counter and the ampersand? - - It works for the counter, but not sure if also for the latter.

Comment: `nl -s ' &' /path/to/file`.  `-s` specifies what separates the numbers from the body of the input file.

Comment: `nl` differs from `cat -n` and the `awk` solution in that it does not number empty lines by default

Answer (score 11):

This achieves what you're after.  (as does `awk '$0=NR" & "$0' filename`, but that's a bit cryptic)

```
awk '{print NR,"&",$0}' filename
1 & What & South Dragon & North Dragon    & 5 \\ \hline
2 & What & South Dragon & North Dragon    & 5 \\ \hline
3 & What & South Dragon & North Dragon    & 5 \\ \hline
```

Or if `sed` preferable, this gives same result.

```
sed = filename | sed 'N;s/\n/ \& /'
```

`perl` approaches.

```
perl -pe '$_="$. & $_"' filename
perl -pe 's/^/$. & /' filename
```

Comment: How did you find this syntax `sed = filename | ...`? - - I did not know that you can use sed with `equal` symbol. - - Can your `sed` statement work in dynamic environments? Any weaknesses?

Comment: @LéoLéopoldHertz준영 I looked under man page, the `=` operator is under "Zero- or One- address Commands" section.

Comment: Yes, `=      Print the current line number`. So the feature is actually built-in in sed. Nice!

Answer (score 3):

Python can be a good alternative tool for this:

```
$ python -c "import sys;lines=[str(i)+' & '+l for i,l in enumerate(sys.stdin,1)]; print ''.join(lines)" < input.txt      
1 & What & South Dragon & North Dragon    & 5 \\ \hline
2 & What & South Dragon & North Dragon    & 5 \\ \hline
3 & What & South Dragon & North Dragon    & 5 \\ \hline
```

The way this works is that we redirect text into python's stdin, and read lines from there. `enumerate()` function is what gives line count, with `sys.stdin` specified as input and `1` is the starting index. The rest is simple - we make up list of new strings by casting index as string joined together with `' & '` string, and the line itself. Finally, all that is reassembled from list into one test by the `''.join()` function.

Alternatively , here's a multi-line version for a script file or simply for readability:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys

for index,line in enumerate(sys.stdin,1):
    print str(index) + ' & ' + line.strip()
```

Works just the same:

```
$ ./line_counter.py  < input.txt                                                                                         
1 & What & South Dragon & North Dragon    & 5 \\ \hline
2 & What & South Dragon & North Dragon    & 5 \\ \hline
3 & What & South Dragon & North Dragon    & 5 \\ \hline
```

But if you prefer doing it in bash, then that can be done as well:

```
$ counter=1; while read line ; do printf "%s & %s\n" "$counter" "$line" ; counter=$(($counter+1)) ; done < input.txt
1 & What & South Dragon & North Dragon    & 5 \ hline
2 & What & South Dragon & North Dragon    & 5 \ hline
3 & What & South Dragon & North Dragon    & 5 \ hline
```

Comment: @LéoLéopoldHertz준영  Well, if I were to do that without enumerate, I would need a variable that tracks number of lines, and I need to initiate that variable, and increment each time. Using `enumerate()` saves up like 3 lines of code. It is useful when dealing with other things, like processing items in lists. See https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate

Comment: @LéoLéopoldHertz준영 if you understand using counter like I do in `bash` example, then feel free to use that :) I just found from experience `enumerate()` to be more elegant, but that's just my opinion. By all means, use other method if you think it's more clear

Comment: OK, `enumerate` is clearer than variable instantiation. Can lambda expression save some space?

Comment: @LéoLéopoldHertz준영  It could save space in a long script, but in this case, i just don't see how that could help.

Answer (score 2):

This is also an option using `cat -n` with auto numbering:

```
while read num line;do echo $num "&" $line;done <<<$(cat -n a.txt)
```